# R shiny apps: choropleth time scale map

Tags: r, shiny, maps, leaflet

I've been using these two guides to make a time scale choropleth map in R shiny, I am quite new to this.

http://journocode.com/2016/01/28/your-first-choropleth-map/

https://rpubs.com/walkerke/leaflet_choropleth

In the first example the time scale is created using two separate csvs that represent year. Is it possible to use one csv with one column that represents years (2009-2016) instead? For example one county polygon may look like this with "variable" being the year, and "value" being the values shown in the choropleth :

```
head(merge)
     CDNAME  id variable value CDUID CDTYPE PRUID  PRNAME
1 Algoma   1     2016     1  3557    DIS    35 Ontario
2 Algoma  99     2014     3  3557    DIS    35 Ontario
3 Algoma 197     2012     0  3557    DIS    35 Ontario
4 Algoma 246     2011     2  3557    DIS    35 Ontario
5 Algoma 344     2009     3  3557    DIS    35 Ontario
6 Algoma  50     2015     3  3557    DIS    35 Ontario
```

My example code is as follows from link #2:

```
library(shiny)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)
library(plyr)
onC <- readOGR("C:\\Users\\app\\data", layer="OntarioCounties", encoding="utf-8" )
timeseries <- read.csv("timeseries.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(timeseries) <- sub('CountyList', 'CDNAME', names(timeseries))
merge <- sp::merge(timeseries,onC, by="CDNAME", duplicateGeoms=TRUE)



palette <- colorBin(c('#fee0d2',  #an example color scheme. you can substitute your own colors
                      '#fcbba1',
                      '#fc9272',
                      '#fb6a4a',
                      '#ef3b2c',
                      '#cb181d',
                      '#a50f15',
                      '#67000d'), 
                    bins = c(0, 5, 8, 10, 12, 14, 18, 24, 32))



state_popup <- paste0("<strong>County: </strong>", 
                      merge$CDNAME,
                      "</br><strong> Year: </strong>",
                      merge$variable,
                      "</br><strong> # of Projects funded: </strong>",
                      merge$value)

mymap<-leaflet(data = onC) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor= palette(merge$value),
              fillOpacity = 0.8, 
              color = "#BDBDC3", 
              weight = 1 ,
              popup = state_popup)
```

Comment: Did you find your answer? Or may I help you?

Comment: Hi @Marie-LouiseJournocode, I did in the end figure it out. I have been meaning to write up a tutorial but haven't found the time as of yet, thanks!

Comment: Great! And I would love to read your tutorial on this whenever you find the time!

Comment: @Marie-LouiseJournocode just realized who you were! Thanks a lot, your website really helped me understand the fundamentals :) will post !

Comment: So happy that it was helpful!